# How can i recursivelry convert Long to LocalDateTime with mapStruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I try to convert one complex object to another complex object. All the object have sub-object.
In theses object, i have date with differents format...

Look at that :

```
ObjectA : {
  Long dateA,
  CustomObject: {
    Long dateB
    List<CustomObject2> myObject
  }
}

CustomObject2 : {
  Long dateC
}
```

And then my destination object :

```
ObjectB : {
  LocalDateTime dateA,
  CustomObject: {
    LocalDateTime dateB
    List<CustomObject3> myObject
  }
}

CustomObject3 : {
  LocalDateTime dateC
}
```

I have write mapstruct converter to convert `ObjectA` to `ObjectB`:

```
@Mapping( target = "dateA", qualifiedByName = "toLocalDateTime")
ObjectB convertROToBO(ObjectA in);

@Named("toLocalDateTime")
static LocalDateTime toLocalDate(final Long dateMilliseconds) {

    if (dateMilliseconds == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateMilliseconds).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();

}
```

So, when i convert my `ObjectA` to `ObjectB`, only my `dateA` is converted (my `dateB` @ `dateC` are not converted).

*** How can i convert all my Long to LocalDateTime recursively with map struct ? Is it possible to do that with single converter and single convertion method ? ***

Thanks :)

Comment: Isn't because you're using `target = "dateA"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your `toLocalDate` is not recursively picked up is because you are using `@Named`, when you qualify your methods they can only be used in combination with `qualifiedByName` and `qualifiedBy`.

If you remove `@Named` from the `toLocalDate` then  all mappings between `Long` and `LocalDateTime` will use that method.